# Attack angle in high speed

Tags: stall

[image]

I found the above animation; the moving slow air (or wing) will hardly to lead to an aerodynamic stall, but the usual case is a plane in the air running much faster than the animation, so does the wing with such attack angle and high speed make an aerodynamic stall?

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what you are asking. I think I get it, but it shouldn't be this difficult to figure out or guess what you are after. Please, if English is your second language I would urge you to find a CFI or aviation-smart mentor in your native language who can help further your understanding. Alternately, if they don't have the answers, perhaps someone could help you translate your question into a grammatically correct sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Stalls happen at (or above) the critical AoA regardless of speed.

However, lift varies with AoA and speed, so if you increase the airspeed at the same AoA, the plane will climb.  Assuming you want to maintain altitude, when you increase airspeed, you will also *reduce* the AoA to compensate.

Stalls almost always happen in the reverse of that scenario: the aircraft is slow, which means the pilot must *increase* AoA to keep generating enough lift to maintain altitude. But without adding sufficient thrust to compensate, this reduces airspeed and thus lift, so the pilot increases AoA further. This vicious cycle continues until the critical AoA is reached and the wing stalls.